# Logstash keeps overwriting Elasticsearch index template

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, logstash

I am sending log data to Elasticsearch database using Logstash. I wanted to change the number of shards from 3 to 1 and issued the following command via ES REST API:

```
PUT server_name/_template/logstash
{
    "template": "logstash",
        "settings": {
            "index.number_of_replicas": "0",
            "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
            "index.number_of_shards": "1"
        }
}
```

The server responsed OK and if I issue GET _template/logstash I can see that the number of shards is now set to 1.

Then I start logstash with an output set to ship logs to Elasticsearch. There are not template-related settings. After I send log data I see that the number of shards is set back to its default value (3).

I even tried to override it by referring template from Logstash configuration file. Nope, whatever I specify the settings are reset back. It looks like Logstash keeps on overwriting Elasticsearch index settings with some defaults, and I can't figure out how to disable this.

UPDATE. I've added the following lines to the Logstash config file but it didn't help:

```
    manage_template => false
    template_overwrite => true
```

Also tried template_overwrite set to false. And I tried two different ways of setting number of shards in the JSON file:

```
{
    "logstash": {
        "template": "logstash-*",
        "settings": {
            "index.number_of_replicas": "0",
            "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
            "index.number_of_shards": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "settings" : {
        "index.number_of_shards" : 1,
        "index.number_of_replicas" : 0,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after many hours I've found the following:

1. The main reason for overwriting Logstash template was that I had two Elasticsearch parts in Logstash output section with conditional selection (if/else). Even though I correctly configured index settings in  the first ("if") part, as soon as Logstash encountered logs that satisfied the other ("else") part, it used default template that overwrote the custom one.
2. "manage_template" option is important. It has to be set to "true" for the configuration block that refers to the custom template settings file, and "false" for the block that shouldn't overwrite the custom Logstash template.

Answer (score 1):

On you `elasticsearch {}` element in your Logstash configuration, you need to add `manage_template => false` if you want to manage the template outside of logstash.

Comment: I've added the following lines to the config:
  manage_template => false
  template_overwrite => true

But I am still getting default number of shards after I delete the index and restart Logstash.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that too. Mystery. Still reset. I've also posted the content of my JSON file.

Comment: And you deleted the logstash-* indexes? -- ie `curl localhost:9200/_cat/shards | grep logstash` shows no indexes/shards? Because you can't change the number of shards on an already created index.

Comment: Yes I am deleting every time indexes that I use for testing.

Comment: Do you perhaps have another copy of logstash running with different settings? (ie `GET localhost:9200/_cluster/state/nodes?pretty`) show any logstash nodes (my cluster shows 3 because I have multiple copies of logstash running)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it when I get to work.

Comment: I eventually managed to solve the issue, see my own answer. Thank you for your help.